# Is it legitimate behaviour to post an off-site solution to a closed question?

Tags: discussion, answers, closed-questions

[This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48671716/how-to-write-a-column-of-data-into-a-file?noredirect=1#comment84346544_48671716) is from someone who had prepared an answer to a no-code question which had been closed as "unclear". I would have preferred "too broad", but the distinction is of little importance

The answerer edited the question to prefix it with a rant about how they should have been allowed to post their answer. They then posted the comment with a link to their solution on github.

This seems completely out of order. Do others agree?

Comment: Meh. If someone really wants to invest energy in answering a bad question and do one-on-one mentoring for someone too lazy to read the manual, why not let them. Hard to see this really harming the site. It's bound to be rare enough anyway, this kind of activity is impossible to keep up even for the biggest good Samaritan out there. The question edit is a different thing; that's absolutely out of order!

Comment: Please ping people next time if you're going to name and discuss their actions on meta. That way, they have an opportunity to explain themselves.

Answer (score 14):

Editing the question with a rant is out-of-order, indeed. You rightfully rolled that back. 
If they disagree with the closure, let them make their case in the comments. This particular one should not be reopened. But in general, it is possible that something was closed wrongly, and then a case can be made for reopening.

If a question gets closed, and the answerer happens to have an answer on GitHub... by all means let them post that link in a comment. A link to an off-site resource is, almost by definition, not an answer. But as a comment these things will do, as long as it's not an attempt to drive extra traffic to one's own site.